# Admin Websites and category collection queries

Tags: magento-1.9, category, adminhtml, websites

I am working on my extension under admin panel for "Add New Product". On this page in the left navigation "Websites and Categories" are present. I want to change some conditions on query of both collection. Where is the location of this collection query.

Answer (score 0):

don't change the query because these queries are use in other files too.
for the `categories`  check the block

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Categories.php
```

check this function for category tree

```
public function getRoot($parentNodeCategory = null, $recursionLevel = 3)
    {
        if (!is_null($parentNodeCategory) && $parentNodeCategory->getId()) {
            return $this->getNode($parentNodeCategory, $recursionLevel);
        }
        $root = Mage::registry('root');
        if (is_null($root)) {
            $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');

            if ($storeId) {
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
                $rootId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
            }
            else {
                $rootId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
            }

            $ids = $this->getSelectedCategoriesPathIds($rootId);
            $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
                ->loadByIds($ids, false, false);

            if ($this->getCategory()) {
                $tree->loadEnsuredNodes($this->getCategory(), $tree->getNodeById($rootId));
            }

            $tree->addCollectionData($this->getCategoryCollection());

            $root = $tree->getNodeById($rootId);

            if ($root && $rootId != Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID) {
                $root->setIsVisible(true);
                if ($this->isReadonly()) {
                    $root->setDisabled(true);
                }
            }
            elseif($root && $root->getId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID) {
                $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
            }

            Mage::register('root', $root);
        }

        return $root;
    }
```

for the websites check websites block

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Websites.php
```

for websites check this function

```
public function getChooseFromStoreHtml($storeTo)
    {
        if (!$this->_storeFromHtml) {
            $this->_storeFromHtml = '<select name="copy_to_stores[__store_identifier__]" disabled="disabled">';
            $this->_storeFromHtml.= '<option value="0">'.Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Default Values').'</option>';
            foreach ($this->getWebsiteCollection() as $_website) {
                if (!$this->hasWebsite($_website->getId())) {
                    continue;
                }
                $optGroupLabel = $this->escapeHtml($_website->getName());
                $this->_storeFromHtml .= '<optgroup label="' . $optGroupLabel . '"></optgroup>';
                foreach ($this->getGroupCollection($_website) as $_group) {
                    $optGroupName = $this->escapeHtml($_group->getName());
                    $this->_storeFromHtml .= '<optgroup label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $optGroupName . '">';
                    foreach ($this->getStoreCollection($_group) as $_store) {
                        $this->_storeFromHtml .= '<option value="' . $_store->getId() . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        $this->_storeFromHtml .= $this->escapeHtml($_store->getName()) . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                $this->_storeFromHtml .= '</optgroup>';
            }
            $this->_storeFromHtml .= '</select>';
        }
        return str_replace('__store_identifier__', $storeTo->getId(), $this->_storeFromHtml);
    }
}
```